# View BIM 360 & Fusion models Unable to load model：Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: autodesk-forge

I did it according to the example on the official website, but the model couldn't be loaded。I don't know why, I followed the tutorial, and I checked the API should be open normally，I think I need help. Here's a screenshot of the error；
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible explanations for this type of error:

1. The model is coming from A360 or Fusion Teams. If that's the case, please note that models uploaded to these applications are **not** translated automatically by the Forge Model Derivative service (hence the viewer error stating that there are no "viewables" to load). You have to open the designs in their owning application first to initiate the translation process, and then you can try accessing them from your own Forge application.
2. It's possible that the sample application is having issues with some of the characters used in the file names. Check if the same error happens when you name your files using English alphabet.